# Are there some other polymorphism forms in Python except duck typing and method dispatching?

Tags: python, polymorphism

In my shallow opinion, polymorphism includes duck typing and methods (or functions) dispatching in Python. The duck typing is well and elegantly supported by Python. For methods dispatching, there is `singledispatch` in `functools`, and with the help of `decorator`, other forms of dispatching can be realized in a graceful manner. So my question is, are there some other polymorphism forms?

I'm not experienced in programming, so maybe my understanding is superficial or even wrong. Please be kind to give an explain.